# adding client timezone from server side

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

My server c# code uses UiAdaptor to send to the client a Date time string.

I want this string to be according to the client time zone and
to include the timezone in the returned string.

What's the recommended way to do so? Investigating httpRequest?
Can I investigate httpRequest in a BLL class (not inherit from web.Page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the timezone in the Date [HTTP header field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). So investigating httpRequest is the way to go

### update

I went to [this website which shows the HTTP request header sent by your browser](http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php) and noticed that it wasn't sending the date. I'm not sure why that might be, but if the date *was* in the request, it would be in the Date field.

Otherwise, you can't readily discover the time zone the user is in (I suppose you could trace the hostname or some other thing, which would be unreliable).

Most services that care about time zones (forums, google calendar, etc) will ask you which you're in. I suspect this is why.

Comment: tried  var dateHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Date"];
and got null

Comment: @EladBenda Based on the fact that you accepted my answer I'm guessing you solved the null problem?

Comment: no. I want to parse dateTime to the following format: Sun Nov 14 43745 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time). btw, what's the '43745' part?

Comment: @EladBenda I don't know, it looks like that's where the year should go... where did that date come from?